# Topology of finite complements

Tags: general-topology

Show that the topology of finite complements is the coarsest topology on any set $X$ for which single points are closed sets.

Comment: It is easier for us to help you when you show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Hint: if singletons are closed, then so are finite sets.

Answer (score 2):

This is really pretty straightforward, so it’s hard to give a hint without simply doing the problem in its entirety, but I’ll try. Let $\tau$ be the coarsest topology on $X$ making all of the sets $\{x\}$ with $x\in X$ closed. You need to show that $\tau$ contains every cofinite subset of $X$.

You know that $X\setminus\{x\}\in\tau$ for each $x\in X$, so you also know right away that at least $\tau$ contains ever complement of a one-element set. Let $F=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ be any finite subset of $X$, and let $U=X\setminus F$; you need to show that $U\in\tau$. You should also know that an intersection of finitely many open sets is also open. Try to use that fact to show that $U\in\tau$.

Once you’ve done that, you’ll have shown that $\tau_c\subseteq\tau$, where $\tau_c$ is the cofinite topology. And $\tau$ is the coarsest topology making all of the singletons closed, so you can’t have $\tau_c\subsetneqq\tau$; why? And what can you conclude from this?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is more convenient to deal with closed sets directly. If $\tau$ is a topology on a set $X$, then we can define $\mathcal F_\tau$ to be the system of all closed sets with respect to $\tau$, i.e. $\mathcal F_\tau=\{X-U\mid U\in\tau\}$. This system satisfies the axioms

1. The empty set and $X$ are in $\mathcal F$.
2. The intersection of any collection of sets in $\mathcal F$ is also in $\mathcal F$.
3. The union of finitely many set in $\mathcal F$ is also in $\mathcal F$.

If, conversely, a system of sets $\mathcal F$ satisfies these axioms, it can be used to define the topology. This is the approach via closed sets.

It is trivial that $\tau_1\subseteq\tau_2$ iff $\mathcal F_{\tau_1}\subseteq \mathcal F_{\tau_2}$. One can easily show that $\bigcap_i \mathcal F_{\tau_i}=\mathcal F_{\bigcap_i \tau_i}$. So the intersection of $\mathcal F$-systems is again an $\mathcal F$-system.

To solve your problem, let $\tau$ be the cofinite topology, so $\mathcal F_\tau$ is the system of all finite sets. You have to show that every finite subset of $X$ is an element of every $\mathcal F$-system containing all singletons. This gives you one inclusion. For the reverse inclusion, note that $\mathcal F_\tau$ itself contains all singletons, so it takes part in the intersection.

One point I'd like to remark is the following: The intersection of all topologies with a certain property $P$ need not itself satisfy $P$. In the problem above, it is trivial, since the intersection of $\mathcal F$-systems containing all singletons also contains all singletons. So if we had not known about the explicit description (the *cofinite* topology) of this coarsest $T_1$-topology, we still would have known that it exists.

I have to say that I just started thinking about the last point when writing this answer, so I don't know about any examples for this failure. Maybe there is a space where the intersection of all $T_2$-topologies is not itself $T_2$.